# htaccess Force HTTPS traffic except one domain

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I am trying to force all traffic to HTTPS except one domain, however, I cannot get this to work.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Exclude the following site
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !excluded\.example.com [NC]

# For the rest of sites force HTTPS traffic. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Result > All websites redirect to HTTPS, including **excluded.example.com** which is not what I need. I would like to exclude that domain from HTTPS

Appreciate if someone spot what I am doing wrong

Many thanks

Comment: You do realise that _condition_ is commented out, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Exclude the following site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^excluded\.example\.com$ [NC]

# For the rest of sites force HTTPS traffic. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Uncommented your RewriteCond and added an escape character. The `^` marks the start of the string and `$` marks the end. Please let me know if this doesn't work out!

Comment: Thanks, yes that works perfectly fine. The comment was still there as I forgot to remove before posting it here.  I guess my Regex was not matching

Comment: @Matias _Your_ regex is even more general, so it would have certainly matched if the (more restrictive) regex above matched. It's likely that you were seeing a cached response, if nothing else has changed.

Comment: Hi DocRoot, i am checking all HTTP responses with a third party to avoid that. Interesting thenI am stil not sure what was wrong.